# Backslash quoting in Byron Rakitzis's RC

Tags: shell, rc-shell

Instead of a mainstream shell like Bash, I use Byron Rakitzis's RC.

I would prefer for RC to behave differently in one particular.  Since I imagine many other users of RC would also prefer the difference, I am hereby asking if someone else had already implemented the different behavior and is willing to share.

In most shells, e.g., Bash, you can use backslash to quote the next character.  So for example, if you wish to refer to a file with the 3-character name hash-space-hash (`# #`) you can refer to it with the 6-character sequence backslash hash backslash space backslash hash.   In contrast, in RC backslash is an ordinary character (unless it occurs at the end of the line).

In summary, I am looking for a patch that makes backslash in RC behave like it does in most other shells.